# Marker cluster in tmap

Tags: r, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster, tmap

I am currently using `tmap` to create interactive maps. Since the results are quite cluttered at initial zoom (see image below), I would like to implement marker clusters.

[image]

I know leaflet allows using marker clusters by adding the parameter `clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()` to `addMarkers()` or `addCircleMarkers()` calls (Source: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) but haven't found how to achieve that using `tmap`.

How can I add marker clusters in `tmap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone from the future is curious, `tmap` supports clustering  by setting `clustering = TRUE` in  `tm_symbols`.

```
library(tmap)

data(metro)
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(metro) + tm_dots(clustering = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for! I could not find that parameter 8at least when I made the question some years ago)